# how to get the source instance from event arguments?

Tags: c#, wpf

lets say we have a class named MyClass

```
public class MyClass
{
      public bool MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I connected a list of MyClass to a listview (DataContex etc.).

To make the MyClass items look nice, I defined a DataTemplate inside the listView resources.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="x:type local:MyClass">
```

I added an expander for every each line in the DataTemplate. and I added an event.

```
<Expander IsExpanded="Expander_Expanded_Method">
```

In code I have that method-

```
private void Expander_Expanded_Method(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // implement
}
```

How can i get the instace of the MyClass item to change it's MyProperty value?

I have tried to use:

```
private void Expander_Expanded_Method(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  (sender as MyClass).MyProperty = something; // doesn't work :-(
  (e.Source as MyClass).MyProperty = something // doesn't work :-(
}
```

I swear I searched for hours for this thing and i didn't found a clue...

I've tried also (as plan B) to find an example of how to change MyProperty of MyClass from XAML by

```
 IsExpanded={binding Path=MyProperty, Mode ="TwoWays"}
```

but it doesn't work either...
Thanks in advance

**Edit**

as Sheridan suggests i'll add more information. and i'll try to make it very simple:

- I have a listView ui
- and a list of MyClass
- the MyClass List inserted inside the listView
- inside every MyClass instance there is a list of MyOtherClass
- the MyOtherClass instances are also inserted inside the listView
- so - we have a listView with 2 kinds of items, MyClass & MyOtherClass
- inside every MyClass there is an expander (done with DataTemplate...)
- i want that the expander state (expand/unexpand) will make the MyOtherClass items that are inside the current MyClass be visible/collapsed

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what you are *actually* trying to do... what value are you trying to change your property to when the `Expander` is expanded?

Comment: Hi. MyClass has a list of items that are also inside the same listview. Each item bind to the MyProperty to set its visibility. I want that when I expand the expander the items will become collapsed. I managed to do it all. Just need to set the Myproperty by the expander as I mentioned and will be great! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking questions on StackOverflow, it is *always* a good idea to explain what your overall goal is. Often users will ask one thing, but unfortunately they've often gone down the wrong path whilst experimenting and are not in fact asking the right question. If you just want to data bind from the `Expander.IsExpanded` property to the `Visiblity` property of your collection, then you could try something like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyClass}">
    <Expander Name="Expander">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="ListBox.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, 
ElementName=Expander}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ListBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
        </ListBox>
    </Expander>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response - i added an edit due to your suggest. due to what i wrote, your answer is still relevant? tnx

Comment: Yes it's still relevant... did you try it?

Comment: great tnx, i am trying it right away. sorry about the delay.it's just that i ask in one computer and run for other to program... no Internet in the other one.

Comment: ok i tried it and it doesn't work. I insert exactly what you had suggest. more info - i made the MyOtherClass list in the MyClass to be ObservableCollection and in the binding in the ItemsSource i made it like that: ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyOtherClassList}" while MyOtherClassList is the name of the property inside MyClass

Comment: I don't know what to tell you... you said *I want that when I expand the expander the items will become collapsed*. That's exactly what this code does. Try changing the `True` to `False` in the `DataTrigger` and you should see. It *might* be an idea for you to test this in a new project... when you fully understand it, then add it back into your current one.

Comment: U r awsome don't give up on me :-) I did what you said and change true to false and boom. The items on the list view I want to dissappear just filled into the expander. So now I have those items in two places. Maybe I need to clearify that those items are at the same level as their father in the listview. And the expander on the father item is just suppose to be without content. And when it expaned the items that are in the father list will collapsed. Tnx dude for the patience

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean property IsExpanded to MyClass, bind the IsExpanded property of the expander to that, MyClass should implement INotifyPropertyChanged if it doesn't.

```
public class MyClass
{
      public bool MyProperty {get;set;}
      public bool IsExpanded {get;set;}
      public MyClass()
      {
          PropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
          {
              if (e.PropertyName == "IsExpanded")
                   // change properties
          }
      }
}

<Expander IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
```

Comment: tried it - doesn't work. i did MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged and created a public event of PropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

I'd ensure that your DataTemplate is correctly applied to the ListView's ItemTemplate.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyClass}">
            <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <TextBlock>MyClass instance</TextBlock>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: tnx dude i'll check it